# Using report viewer, how do I pull from two seperate Datasets

Tags: c#, reportviewer, rdlc

I have two datasets I need to pull from, A base that both reports use and then a separate one that only one report pulls from. I get the error

> Error 12  The Value expression for the text box ‘Textbox9’ refers to
>   the field ‘Name’.  Report item expressions can only refer to fields
>   within the current dataset scope or, if inside an aggregate, the
>   specified dataset scope.

My best guess is I have to associate them with the correct dataset but I have not been able to find any documentation on this.

edit: I am trying to access property files that I created for the fields on the report document.

Can someone please tell me where in the `rdlc` document I need to code something like `name.value`, "dataset1" or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some careful research and error checking I found that I had to create my base model property file and when I drag the actual data points on to my form I had to associate them with their correct set:

[image]

I clicked the value and associated the correct dataset.

Comment: how to create base model property file

Answer (score 5):

When you create a table in a RLDC, in the Tablix properties (selecting a row or a column) you must associate a DataSet.

After doing that, you have to write in each cell the name of the field (in the dataset) that you will use. You can do that by clicking on the "little table" in the cell, when you put the mouse over it

In images (with `Visual Studio 2010`)

[image: Tablix Properties]

[image: Selecting DataSet]

[image: Setting Field to Show]

If you don't see the dataset in the list, you must add it.
For that, click on view menu -> report data.
Then, in the `DummyDataSource`, click `Add Dataset..`

[image: Add new DummyDataSource]

And select it from the list, or create a new one instead, in the same form.
[image]

If this doesn't work, well I don't know haha

If the two datasets has the same structure, then you could use one just, and in the code assign it to the datasource

Comment: I am not using a database as the stat set. I am actually using an object manually created from a properties file. We do not want to directly query the database repeatedly for the same data. We want it to live in memory. I have figured out what I have to do and I'll post my answer now

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same error and the only way I could resolve it was by closing and reopening BIDS and then refreshing the fields from the stored procedure (Right click the data set -> Dataset Propoerties -> Query -> Refresh Fields).

Thanks for the troubleshooting tips!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to embed the results of one set into a table that is using another data set, have you considered a subreport?

Comment: Not quite what I am trying to do.